# VMware USB HDD not showing in "Removable Devices"

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a USB hard drive that I want to attach to VMware Workstation 12.5 running on a Manjaro Linux host.
The HDD is accessible by the device named `/dev/sdc`.

I have added a virtual USB controller, but the disk does not appear under `VM` -> `Removable Devices`.

How do I get the disk to show in `Removable Devices`?

Do I need to somehow disconnect the disk from the host before connecting it to VMware? How?

<sub>Note: I'm getting some strange partition table issues when creating a virtual disk using the physical disk, so I want to go down the USB device route, not the virtual disk route. When using a virtual disk, the guest OS (Windows) is seeing a blocksize of 512, whereas the host is showing 4096.</sub>

Comment: Can't recall how they do it in VMWare Workstation, but it is an engineering rule that only one system may mount a filesystem at any given time, unless sophisticated hardware and filesystems are in use, so desktop vm solutions must unmount the disk from the local system when passing control through to the VM.

Comment: I can confirm that none of the device's partitions are mounted.